# Trying to get lights to correspond with lab

Tags: python, led

Hello so i made an reaction time game as when you hit the enter key to start the game, you wait for the light to turn on then you hit the button to end the game. so for the reaction light i have that fully working with the lab but my problem is that my two other lights are not working. these lights are for is you have a good reacting time, then the green light will turn on. but if you have a bad reacting time. then the red will turn on. both will not work for me and i don't understand the problem.
`

## Reaction Time Lab

```
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 import time
 from time import time as the_timer
 import random

#Setup GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#Button LED setup
led = 19,12,22
button = 21

#GPIO setup channels for the pins 
GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(button, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

GPIO.output(12,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(22,GPIO.LOW)

#Introduction to the lab and pressing enter to input th start of the lab

print("Welcome to the reaction time lab. here we will want you to  press 
the button as soon at the light turn"
  "on too see if you have a good reaction time or not." "if you recieved the Green LED, then you have a"
  "good reacting time.  If you recieved the Red LED, then you have a bad reacting time.")       
input("press enter to start")
wait_time = (random.randint(5,10))
print(wait_time)
GPIO.output(19,GPIO.LOW)
time.sleep(wait_time)
GPIO.output(19,GPIO.HIGH)
start_time = the_timer()


try:
    while(1):
        if (GPIO.input(button) == False):
            print("Button Pressed")
            break 
    end_time = the_timer()

    print("Started at" +time.strftime("%X", time.localtime(start_time)))
    print("Ended at" +time.strftime("%X", time.localtime(end_time)))

    print("Your reaction time was {}".format(end_time - start_time))
#Led color lights up depending on the reaction time.
    if (format(end_time - start_time < 1)):
        GPIO.output(22,GPIO.HIGH)   
    else: 
        GPIO.output(12,GPIO.HIGH)
  
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Reset Program")
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()`
```

can anyone show me what my problem is with my code?

Comment: Would it work if you just said  if (end_time - start_time < 1.0): ?

Comment: What does it mean when you say "both will not work for me". What happens exactly? Does green/red stay on forever? Does it ever change?

Comment: @hikerjobs the green or red light doesn't turn on after i press the button completing the reaction game

Comment: Does it print any of the stuff in your print statements, e.g., print("Started at" ...

Comment: @hikerjobs yes it prints all the information regarding what time it started, what time it ended, and what is your reaction time

Comment: It seems like it's your GPIO stuff that's not working. Do these lines work outside of any conditional loops? GPIO.output(22,GPIO.HIGH)   
GPIO.output(12,GPIO.HIGH)

Comment: @hikerjobs no, that my problem but i just don't know what to right now to fix it.

Comment: Just for future reference, if you provide all this information in the first place itself, i.e., in your original question, it'd be faster to arrive where we are at right now. As for the GPIOs, you'd have to try a bunch of things. Try explicitly pushing it LOW and then HIGH. Also try other pins instead of 22, 12.